# Drawing parallels on map

Tags: d3.js

Example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5731693 shows the equator drawn on an equirectangular map, which then transitions to another projection. On the equirectangular projection, the equator is just a straight line running horizontally.

Funny things happen though if I move the parallel to another latitude, say 20⁰. Instead of drawing a straight line 20⁰ above the equator, D3 draws curved segments approaching the 30⁰ parallel midway from the given control points.

Since I'm just starting with D3, I am a bit at loss at what is happening here.

Comment: I'm curious as well... Here's the [**example**](http://bl.ocks.org/jshanley/f671ecf719f904f4941d) with updated coordinates. Why is this happening?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that the path is using the points that have the shortest distance from point A to B, if they were on a sphere of course

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each point is connected with a great arc of the sphere they are placed on. Great arcs are defined as sections of great circles, which in turn are circles that divide a sphere in half.

Great arcs are the shortest paths that connect two points on a sphere. They are the equivalent of going in a strait line across the surface of a sphere. On the equator, which is a great circle (since it divides the globe into the north and south hemispheres), these great arcs are part of the equator forming what looks like a straight line on an equirectanglar projection. Since the 20⁰ latitude line is not a great circle, the most direct path between any two points on it will not lie on the line, and will instead be arcs that lie to the north of the 20⁰ latitude line.

For a great circle, you can use the coordinates `[[-180, 20], [-90, 0], [0, -20], [90, 0], [180, 20]]`